# Why Django QuerySet didn't support join with manyTomany?

Tags: python, django, orm, many-to-many, django-queryset

How can I generate SQL like snippet 1-2?

---

### Why Django support only prefetch_related('product_set') without support join with manytomanyField?

of course i can make similar queryset like

Order.objects.filter(product_set_included_order__name='product_name1')

it generate SQL with join two entity

but it has big problem which didn't hit index(pk)

```py
# 1-1 this is snippet code 
# in Django model of relationship with ManyToMany

class Product(models.Model):
    name: str = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=128)
    price: int = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, default=0)


class Order(models.Model):

   product_set= models.ManyToManyField(to=Product)
```

```
# 1-2  i want generate this SQL but it's impossible!!

SELECT *
  FROM "order"
 INNER JOIN "orderedproduct"
    ON ("order"."id" = "orderedproduct"."related_order_id")
 INNER JOIN "product"
    ON ("orderedproduct"."related_product_id" = "product"."id")
 WHERE "order"."id" = 1;
```